# CreateInertiaApp runs twice

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

After we've setup our laravel + inertia app we found out that CreateInertiaApp() runs twice.

We tried to find a solution but haven't found one yet.

**app.js**

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import DefaultLayout from "../../views/layouts/default";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import { importComponent } from "./import-component.js";
import { ZiggyVue } from "ziggy";
import { Ziggy } from "../../js/ziggy";
import { InertiaProgress } from "@inertiajs/progress";

InertiaProgress.init();
createInertiaApp({
  resolve: (name) => {
    console.log("123");
    const component = importComponent(name);

    // Set default layout if no layout specified on component
    component.default.layout ??= DefaultLayout;
    return component;
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    const pinia = createPinia();
    const app = createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .use(pinia)
      .mixin({ methods: { route: window.route } })
      .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy);

    // added ziggy route helper
    // shows laravel routes in vue
    app.config.globalProperties.$auth = props.initialPage.props.auth;
    app.mount(el);
  },
});
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix
  .js("resources/assets/js/app.js", "public/js")
  .sass("resources/assets/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
  .webpackConfig(aliasesConfig)
  .sourceMaps()
  .vue({ version: 3 })
  .ziggy()
  .version();
```

[image: console log screenshot]

Can you help us?